# My Button always sends me to else even i have the right details

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have my database and my php code working and on the Android Monitor results when i put the right details it logs in successfully. But this code always sends me to the else statement which is Failed login.

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    HashMap postData = new HashMap();
    String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
    postData.put("username",username);
    postData.put("password",password);

    PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData,
            new AsyncResponse() {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(String s) {
                    Log.d(LOG, s);
                    if (s.contains("success")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successful Login!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    task1.execute("http://10.0.2.2/*******/");

}
```

Comment: please share what is printed by this : `Log.d(LOG, s);`

Comment: contains is case sensitive, are you sure that your response is not capitalized or something like this?

Comment: so, what is Log s output?

Comment: `07-03 20:15:48.085 15353-15353/com.example.kun.carcarkila D/MainActivity: Login Successful`
This is what `Log.d(LOG, s);` is printing. But on the emulator the `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` is showing. @AshishRanjan

Comment: @Batz use : `s.equalsIgnoreCase("Login Successful")`  or `s.contains("Success")`  instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should replace `s.contains("success")` with `s.contains("Success")`
as @Victor Ribeiro da Silva Eloy pointed `contains` function is "case sensitive", and in the other hand you pointed that you see "Login Successful" in your logs that it's "Successful" has capital "S".

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure enough that **s** is **success** then try to replace with :-

this

`s.contains("Success")`

Comment: It's still the same what should be inside that contains in order my statement will go right?

Comment: if you want to replace "contains" function with "equalsIgnoreCase" you should pass "Login  Successful" argument to it instead of "success" . because @Batz pointed that he see "Login Successful" in his log's and not "Success"